# Getting an Apache error when using php's shell_exec() to call a java program?

Tags: java, php, apache, shell-exec

I am trying to run a java program called 'Audiveris' with php's `shell_exec()` function. Audiveris is an open source tool for optical music recognition written in java. I am able to call and run small test java files that output a simple string with shell_exec(). However, when I try to call Audiveris I get an error in the Apache Error log. Here is the error message I am getting.

```
May 01, 2020 8:21:04 PM sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2 getPersonal
WARNING: Cannot access 'Personal'
java.io.IOException: Could not get shell folder ID list
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath0(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

May 01, 2020 8:21:04 PM sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2 getDesktop
WARNING: Cannot access 'Desktop'
java.io.IOException: Could not get shell folder ID list
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath0(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.audiveris.omr.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:64)
    at Audiveris.main(Audiveris.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.audiveris.omr.WellKnowns.getFolderForWindows(WellKnowns.java:403)
    at org.audiveris.omr.WellKnowns.getFolder(WellKnowns.java:302)
    at org.audiveris.omr.WellKnowns.<clinit>(WellKnowns.java:141)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is what I am using in shell_exec. All paths are correct and $sheet_music_path is simply the path to the sheet music pdf. I got this command from Audiveris' gitbooks and I am able to use this command in command prompt with no issues.

`shell_exec('java -cp "Audiveris/lib/*" Audiveris -batch -export '.$sheet_music_path);`

I am using Windows 10, jdk8 (required by Audiveris), php 7.3.12, apache 2.4.41 and a Wamp server. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths instead of relative paths for  `Audiveris/lib/*` and `$sheet_music_path`

Comment: Yes I have same issue

Comment: I have found the cause of the error but have still not found a fix yet.  Apparently the line  `final String userDocs = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getPath();`  inside the Audiveris application cannot access the file location and returns null. I still do not know why this is happening as it works fine from the command prompt but not when using PHP's shell_exec().

Comment: try making a bash script file and moving this command to that file, and then from PHP `exec('cd /path/scripts; ./script.sh');`

Comment: Yes, still the same error. Strangely, I am only getting the error in my apache error log but not in my PHP error log.

Comment: I created a simple java file which outputted `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getPath()` which gets the default directory of the system. And I get the same errors so apache must be blocking access to Documents/Desktop or something?